# Single formula with Multiple Countifs and where data table contains duplicate values in more than one column

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique, countif

The excel file contains a structure table. (which I find difficult to work with but I can't alter the file structure, I am just adding a summary tab with various counts from the data table.)

| Item | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

The item number itself can repeat and be repeated within the same month.

I was able to get a count of total number of unique items using this formula.
`=SUMPRODUCT((Item_tab[Item]<>"")/COUNTIF(Item_tab[Item],Item_tab[Item]&""))`

Looking for how to count the number of unique items within a specific month.?

Example of Desired output.
Edit/Set formula for Month 2 , output should be 2
Edit/Set formula for Month 3 , output should be 2
Edit/Set formula for Month 4 , output should be 1

I cannot figure out how to apply countifs to something that needs to avoid duplicates in multiple columns.

Tried this but returns #VALUE!
`=SUMPRODUCT((Item_tab[Item]<>"")/COUNTIFS(Item_tab[Item],Item_tab[Item]&"",'Item'!M:M,6))`

The month column was added later and I don't know how why or how to get that column to have the structured table column Header like everything else.
The sheet name is Item
The Table Name is Item_tab
I can find where to rename the table but not the columns. Not sure the variance is causing an issue. The month column is absolutely part of the table in every way that I can see.

Comment: so you want to count unique items within a given month, right? what is the excel version you have?

Comment: yes exactly. Office365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following in cell `D2`:

```
=LET(A, A2:A7, B, B2:B7, uxB, UNIQUE(B), cnts, BYROW(uxB, LAMBDA(u, 
 ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A, B=u))))), HSTACK(uxB, cnts))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

If you want to get the result repeated instead of consolidating the result by unique months, you can try the following:

```
=LET(A, A2:A7, B, B2:B7, uxB, UNIQUE(B), BYROW(B, LAMBDA(u, 
 ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A, B=u))))))
```

If you don't have such function available, you can try the following formula in `D2`, it produces the same result as the first formula:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2}, UNIQUE(B2:B7),
 MMULT(N(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(B2:B7=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B7)))),
 N(A2:A7=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A7))))>0), SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(A2:A7)),,1,0)))
```

or using `LET` for a better reading and maintenance:

```
=LET(A, A2:A7, B, B2:B7, CHOOSE({1,2}, UNIQUE(B),
 MMULT(N(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N(B=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B)))),
 N(A=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A))))>0), SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(A)),,1,0))))
```

Comment: I get #NAME? "formula contains unrecognized text".  =LET(A, 'Item'!A2:A628, M, 'Item'!M2:M628, uxM, UNIQUE(M), BYROW(M, LAMBDA(u,
 ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A, M=u)))))) I then copied the main data table and deleted everything but ITEM and Month so only Columns A:B and used both options just as you listed them and still #NAME?, then removed the extra spaces I missed from copy/paste and still nothing. Not sure what else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I reproduced your exact formula and scenario on my end and it works, are you sure you have O365 version? LET is from Excel 2021 and BYROW for O365

Comment: In excel, From File tab, under Account, it states Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, and down below says Version 2202. Using a new sheet and using the 7 row example data as you did I still get an error.  
 =LET(A,A2:A7,B,B2:B7,uxB,UNIQUE(B),cnts,BYROW(uxB,LAMBDA(u,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A,B=u))))),HSTACK(uxB,cnts))      if go to show calculation steps the first evaluate shows   =LET(A,#NA,B,#NA,uxB,UNIQUE(#NA),cnts,BYROW(uxB,LAMBDA(u,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A,B=u))))),HSTACK(uxB,cnts))

Comment: @Ben.Name share a link to your excel file (editable). Thanks

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, and Im on a work pc anyway. However, if I type =by... byrow isn't a function that pops up. Also, (no idea if accurate) but one site from google states "Note: BYROW is a beta function available only through the Insiders channel of Excel 365."  So, likely company here doesn't have BYROW or anything beta? Also, if I continue through the calculation steps BYROW does turn into #NAME?(uxB, LAMBDA(u .. etc etc

Comment: @Ben.Name You can upload your sample file in your MS O365 personal account, and then share the link for example this is the [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih3hSA1xf0a6yKNk-?e=55cNen) to my sample file. You can check that is working. If you have O365 you have `BYROW`, check the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) as well as the other functions I use

Comment: "This site can't be reached" .... likely a Company PC restriction. I can view it on my own laptop but cannot recreate it as I only have Office2019. I did however come up with a janky two step solution of sorts. I make a new hidden sheet and in A1 put =FILTER('Item'!A:A,'Item'!M:M=B2,"") and B2 I enter a month number. Then on dashboard use =SUM(IF(A1#<>"",1/COUNTIF(A1#, A1#), 0)) ...Thank you for all your help, wish there was way without the newer functions

Comment: I shared the link so you can check the solution is working so you can accept it or/and up-vote it. It should not require a helper column if you have the correct version. You can create a personal MS Office account (this is what I have, it is free) that is the Excel web version, and you can upload your files and then work with it from the browser. This is what I was referring. My excel desktop version at work is Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20196) 64-bit. It also works. You should be able to see `BYROW` under MS O365.

Comment: I will upvote for now, fingers crossed for another solution. rather avoid another post explicitly asking to not use new functions. Curious, when you go to account do you see "Office Insider" ? https://insider.office.com/en-us/join/windows ...Under Product Information, you may see Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise, or there may not be any license specified. You won’t see the option to install or manage Insider builds unless your administrator has enabled it....likely my admin-dept has this killed....also, availability https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/new-lambda-functions-available-in-excel

Comment: I see your problem, the only function that has some availability limitation is `HSTACK` for Windows 2208 and you have 2202, but you can replace it with `CHOOSE`, as follow: `=LET(A, A2:A7, B, B2:B7, uxB, UNIQUE(B), cnts, BYROW(uxB, LAMBDA(u, ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A, B=u))))), CHOOSE({1,2},uxB, cnts))` Try this, because `BYROW` or `LET` don't have such limitations.

Comment: @Ben.Name see my updated answer with a solution that doesn't require `BYROW' using `MMULT`. I don't think you are going to have any excel limitation with this approach. Let me know or accept the answer. You can test it step by step to understand it.

Comment: Using `LET` is super fast compared to using `CHOOSE`. Also, the 'CHOOSE' option seems to work best if define a specific range like A2:A628 where `LET` seems to still work well with a full column range like Item_tab[ITEM] and Item_tab[Month] ...(structured tables and their column headers still bug me, rather use name manager on a normal range). I was hoping for a single cell result where I could hardcode a month into the formula for specific dashboard cells, though maybe I can still and I just dont understand this enough yet. This is more complex than anticipated. ..anyway, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: thanks, so the problem was `HSTACK`so you can use the first formula but using `CHOOSE`, of did you use the formula with the `MMULT`? I am curious which excel function was giving you problems. Thanks

Comment: They both use `MMULT` ? __The `LET` solution is better. __ For `CHOOSE` when using a full column range (for me) kicks an additional and last row of zero month and item count of 1, (I think its blanks?) also it adds a top row and kicks out the column header "Month" and a cont of one.  =CHOOSE({1,2}, UNIQUE('Item'!M:M),
 MMULT(N(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(N('Item'!M:M=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE('Item'!M:M)))),
 N('Item'!A:A=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE('Item'!A:A))))>0), SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE('Item'!A:A)),,1,0))) __If I change to 'Item'!M2:M628 and 'Item'!A2:A628 if works just like the `LET` does with full ranges.